# Not Found: /1/${url}data

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I want to show a list of question on my quiz.html templates...
Here is my views.py

```
def quiz_data_view(request,pk):
quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)
questions = []

for q in quiz.get_questions():
    answers = []
    for a in q.get_answers():
        answers.append(a.text)
    questions.append({str(q):answers})
return JsonResponse({
    'data' : questions,
    'time' : quiz.time,
})
```

Here is my js file...in my js file i used ajax...

```
   const url = window.location.href
   const quizBox = document.getElementById('quiz-box')
   let data
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "${url}data",
    success : function(response){
        // console.log(response)
        data = response.data
        data.forEach(el=>{

            for(const [question,answers] of Object.entries(el)){
                quizBox.innerHTML +=`
                    <hr>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                      <b>  ${question}</b>
                    </div>
                `
            }

        });
    },
    error : function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    QuizListView,quiz_view,quiz_data_view
)
app_name='quizes'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',QuizListView.as_view(),name='main-view'),
    path('<int:pk>/',quiz_view,name='quiz-view'),
    path('<int:pk>/data/',quiz_data_view,name='quiz-data-view'),
]
```

Here is my models.py

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

    DIFF_CHOICE = (
        ('easy','easy'),
        ('medium','medium'),
        ('hard','hard'),
    )
    
    class Quiz(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        topic = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        number_of_question = models.IntegerField()
        time = models.IntegerField(help_text="Duration in Minutes")
        required_score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(help_text="Required Score to Pass in %")
        difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=DIFF_CHOICE)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.name}-{self.topic}"
        
        def get_questions(self):
           self.question_set.all()[:self.number_of_question]
           
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Quizes'
```

and here is my quiz.html....and here i want to show my question list

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'quizes/quiz.js' %}" defer></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
{% block title %}
    {{obj.name}}
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{{obj.name}}
<hr>

<form id ="quiz-form" class="mt-3 mb-3">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="quiz-box"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Save
    </button>


</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

But I don't get my question list in the  template

IT Shows this error **Not Found: /1/${url}data**

Comment: `"${url}data"` needs to be surrounded in backticks ( `\`` ) not quotes when wanting to use template literals, eg `\`${url}data\``